# How to handle dynamic require images react native

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, react-native, multer, mern

1. i saved images to MongoDb with multer to path /uploads in my local static folder.
2. the object that i get from the data base when i get images look like :

   ```
     Array [
   Object {
   "_id": "5fc4581a1b858e93a65136e7",
   "desc": "19",
   "image": "uploads/a2.jpg",
    },
    Object {
   "_id": "5fc4584a873e544138a10a33",
   "desc": "19",
   "image": "uploads/a2.jpg",
   },
   ]
   ```
3. now i want to show the array with desc and image so i defined a flat list  and try to do:

   ```
           <FlatList
           numColumns={numColumns}
           data={s}
           renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
               console.log("http://localhost:8080/" + item.image),
               (
                   <View style={styles.imagecontainer}>
                       <Text>{item.desc}</Text>
                       {Object.keys(s).length === 0 ? null : (
                           <Image style={styles.image} source= 
      {require(`../../server/${item.image}`)} />/////////here is the problem
                       )}
                   </View>
               )
           )}
           keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
       />
   ```

- now I understand that require should get only static string and not variables,
- the question is how can I handle this to show the images and desc dynamically based on the array?

I read a lot of it on the internet but Dont find the answer for this...
I need somehow to convert the objects that I get and replace the image prop that gave me "uploads/a2.jpg" to {require(`../../server/**here to put the image for each object**`) but I Dont find a way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue, the only way I found it was to save images' IDs returned by the **require()** function.

```
console.log(require("image path"));
// return a number for example 5
```